# How to serve a static site within keystone?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, keystonejs

I have one keystone based site and a completely static one.

I would like to integrate the static one into the first one. 
All the requests to "/" will serve the static one but requests under "/resources" would serve the keystone site.

basically:

```
"/"            would serve the static folder 'site'
"/resources"   would serve the keystone app
```

At the moment my structure is:

```
public
| - keystone
| - site
```

And my keystone static option is set on 'public'

```
    'static': 'public'
```

How would I go to set up these routes?

I was thinking of using a middleware in this way:

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/site"));
app.use("/resources", express.static(__dirname + "/keystone"));
```

But how would I do it in keystone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need any extra middleware. 
With the option `'static' : 'public'`, any static content placed in the **public** folder within your project folder will be served as static content.

It is also possible to define more than one directory by providing an array of directories like this `'static' : ['public','site']` this way everything in the directory site will also be served.

I assume you want some kind of index.html to be loaded when someone hits your sites root. You can achieve tha by adding a redirect to your `/routes/index.js`.
Simply add `keystone.redirect('/', '/index.html');` or whatever the filename is you want to get served. You also have to remove the keystone route to `'/'`

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this by just editing one line in the `routes/index.js` file, and adding the directory name in the `keystone.init()` "static" setting.  Now all files in "client" directory get served under the root of my site URL, and Keystone lives at `www.yoursite.com/resources`

#### Step 1

Edit `routes/index.js`:

Change:

```
app.get('/', routes.views.index);
```

To:

```
app.get('/resources', routes.views.index);
```

#### Step 2

edit `keystone.js`:

Change

```
keystone.init({
    ...
    'static': 'public',
    ...
```

To

```
keystone.init({
    ...
    'static': ['public','client']
    ...
```

```

#### Step 3

Add site files, including `index.html`, into a new folder called "client".

Keep in mind that Node will also load files that are in the "public" folder.  For example, currently keystone has a file called "logo-email.gif" in `public/images`.  This means that `www.yoursite.com/images/logo-email.gif` will load that image.  It turns out that if there is both a file `public/images/logo-email.gif` and `client/images/logo-email.gif`, then the image in `public` takes precedence.  If you reverse the 'static' attribute in `keystone.init()` so that it says `['client','public']` then the image in "client" takes precedence

Answer (score 1):

KeystoneJS v5, I used this way:

```
module.exports = {
  keystone,
  apps: [
    new GraphQLApp(),
    new StaticApp({path:"/", src:'public'}), // for your static site
    new StaticApp({path:"/resources", src:'static'}), // Keystone uploaded resources
    new AdminUIApp({
      enableDefaultRoute: true,
      authStrategy,
    })
  ]}
```